# How to train a classification algorithm with normalized data set using scikit-learn python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset in CSV format, 6 columns and 1877 rows. The full dataset can be viewed [ShareCSV](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/4e1ed24fe3e1587952747bd73adfcb9b/redditMachineLearning.csv).

The first five columns are characteristics and the final column is a binary result, I want to create a classification network to predict result using the five inputs as seen in the CSV above.

I use the following code to normalize the data with pandas.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\path\data.csv", sep=",")

df=(df-df.min())/(df.max()-df.min())
```

I now need to pass this data to scikit-learn and select a classification algorithm, however this is where I am unsure what would be optimal, if anyone could recommend the best algorithm for my data and a rough implementation that would be great.

Comment: check with Scikit  MinMaxScaler....

Comment: Hi! I feel like your question belongs to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ι would say that you can separate the values by train_test_split and then train those on a classification algorithm by an appropriate metric.

Below is something that I used (for a regression problem though), that you may change to your own needs:

```
X = TRAIN_DS[["season", "holiday", "workingday", "weather", "weekday",
              "month", "year", "hour", 'humidity', 'temperature']]

Y = TRAIN_DS['count']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

estimators = [('randf', RandomForestRegressor(max_depth= 50, n_estimators= 1500)), ('gradb', GradientBoostingRegressor(max_depth= 5, n_estimators= 400)), ('gradb2',GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators= 4000)), ('svr', SVR('rbf',gamma='auto')), ('ext', ExtraTreesRegressor(n_estimators=4000))] 

voting = StackingRegressor(estimators) 
voting.fit(X = X_train, y = np.log1p(y_train))
```

For the best model I would suggest that you use an appropriate metric. Here is an RMSLE and R2 function that you may find useful:

```
'''Calculating RMSLE score, r2 score as well as plotting''' 
def calc_plot(y_test, y_pred, name): 
    # Removing negative values for i, y in enumerate
    (y_pred): if y_pred[i] < 0: y_pred[i] = 0 
    # Printing scoring 
    print('RMSLE for ' + name + ':', np.sqrt(mean_squared_log_error(y_test, y_pred))) 

    print('R2 for ' + name + ':', r2_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

Also you may use [Voting Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.VotingClassifier.html) or [Stacking Classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.StackingClassifier) to use multiple models for your predictions.
Finally you can use [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) to check different values for the parameters of the classification algorithm that you use. An example to a regression problem would be the below:

```
gr = SGDRegressor()

parameters = {'loss':['squared_loss','huber','epsilon_insensitive','squared_epsilon_insensitive'], 'penalty':['l2','l1','elasticnet'],
              'fit_intercept':[True,False], 'learning_rate':['constant','optimal','invscaling','adaptive'], 'alpha':[0.0001,0.005,0.001],
              'l1_ratio':[0.15,0.5,0.25], 'max_iter':[500,1000,2000], 'epsilon':[0.1,0.4], 'eta0':[0.01,0.05,0.1], 'power_t':[0.25,0.1,0.5],
              'early_stopping':[True,False], 'warm_start':[True,False],'average':[True,False], 'n_iter_no_change':[3,5,10,15]}
lModel = GridSearchCV(gr,parameters, cv=LeaveOneOut(), scoring = 'neg_mean_absolute_error')
```

Hope it helps!